# Caching repository object or data results selectively

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, .net-4.0, repository

I've been looking into implementing caching at Repository level using the .NET 4.0 Caching features or via a third party abstraction interface like [this one](https://bitbucket.org/glav/cacheadapter/overview) and I've just run into an issue where I will have to support two use cases.

My application might be split in multiple areas, for instance the Admin area and the User frontend (website frontend). I don't want any caching to take place in the Admin area, Admins should always have the latest refreshed data displayed to them.

now, do I have to refactor all my repository methods to take in a parameter whether to return the cached results or not? Are there any other options?

Comment: What about have a separate repositories, "front end" if you will that is using caching and admin and then you can have both without parameter, tho i admit that is a not a best solution

Comment: it's actually not that bad of a solution paired with the advanced injection logic that IoC containers provide

Comment: Also you can have parameter injection if you are using Ninject :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the caching at the controller level, not at the repositories. This way in the admin area controllers you will always query the repository to get fresh data and in the others you will cache the results. If you absolutely need to do the caching of the objects at the repository layer you need an additional parameter to indicate whether the call is being made from the Admin area or not. Or you could also use a DI framework such as NInject which allows you to pass parameters from the HttpContext to dependencies that are allocated per request lifetime. So you could inject the `area` RouteData parameter to your repository's constructor.

Comment: Two repositories? Cached and not cached and switch between them via Ninject DI? that's something I just thought of..

Answer (score 0):

There are various levels of caching that can be applied since you are using ASP.NET. I would not go about re-inventing the wheel if we have it already there.

We have:

- ASP.NET server caching
- ASP.NET output caching on server (using `[OutputCache]` on the action)
- ASP.NET output caching on client (using `[OutputCache]` on the action)

Entity Framework or other ORMs can do the caching as well. So I would say use what is already there until you are sure it does not do what you need.

---

## UPDATE

If you have to do it at repository, I would suggest use Dependency injection features to inject the right repository (one with caching or no-caching)

Comment: I am aware of these but my scenario requires caching at the repository level.